# How to delete element in List<> from jsp page?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Can you help me? I have some code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>admin panel</h1>
        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.username}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.email}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${item.enabled}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public String adminPanel(ModelMap model)
{
    List<User> users = this.userService.showAllUsers();
    model.addAttribute("users",users);
    return "adminpanel";
}
```

I need to manage users. I have methods in dao and service to take users from database. How do I delete or update user properties from jsp? Something like like datagridview in asp.net mvc

Comment: You can use scriptlet `<% %>` in jsp to write the java code in jsp.

Comment: @Rahul Yuck! Sciplets into a fairly nice MVC architecture above?! Are you serious?

Comment: I think you are searching for something like this:
http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/extjs-spring-mvc-3-and-hibernate-3-5-crud-datagrid-example/
I did not test ist but it seems to me like just what you mean with "datagridview".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Ajax to do this. Add a link to your tag like:

```
<td><a href="/admin/deleteUser?delete=${item.userID}">Delete</td>
<td><a href="/admin/updateUser?update=${item.userID}">Update</td>
```

Call the another controller method annotated as /deleteUser or /updateUser. Then delete or update user and fill the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two more td's in  table like:

```
<td><a href="/yourDeleteAction?delete=${item.userID}">Delete</td>
```

and in controller define method with request mapping `/yourAction` get the query string and delete the user and redirect to same /admin.

for update :

```
<td><a href="/yourUpdateAction?update=${item.userID}">Update</td>
```

1) Get the data for userID and show up on to one screen for update.

2) say update.jsp make changes to that data and submit to a a method in cotroller say /updateDone make database interaction and redirect to /admin

Note: There are lot's of approaches I am just suggesting you this one approach.

Answer (score 0):

The real update, delete shouldn't be happen right from JSP, the JSP should be just making a request and your application on server side should do real database changes and send back the changed data.

For DataGrid Like Feature you can use a JQuery Library which supports JSON requests like [JQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) or any other providing similar features and can easily integrate to your web application.

You should leverage on the Spring's REST URI feature and write your methods according to that.

You can retrieve the data as JSON using @ResponseBody Annotation and use it to populate grid, any cell update can be tied up with an AJAX request to a particular REST method and you can update, delete right from grid still following MVC guidelines.

Hope it helps.